# how to set the width of left div based on the width of the screen

Tags: html, css

Firstly i am using container-fluid bootstrap class to set the width of the main div id='content'. Inside the main div, i have two div's. The right div with id='content_right' must have a fixed width of 330px irrespective of the media query it is in and the left div with id='content_left' must be flexible with the fluid width of the parent div.

```html
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div id='content' class='col-xs-12'>
      <div id='content_left'>
         The width must be flexible with the width of the parent div. 
      </div>
      <div id='content_right'>
         330px width all the time in all bootstrap media queries
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know the solution for the above using jQuery. But i don't want to use any script but instead want the solution using HTML and CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var parentWidth=$("#content").width();
 var left_width=parentWidth-330;
 $("#content_left").width(left_width);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#content_left{
      width: calc(100% - 330px);
      box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

This is possible that you have to add `!important` to last if it (`width: calc(100% - 330px) !important;`).

Comment: One small query...Does 'calc' work on old browsers as well?

Comment: Your welcome @Preetham. I'm glad helped you. It works in ie9 and other famous browsers.

Comment: Yes i did upvote it. But the got the following message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score".

Comment: it is not important my friend :) I thought you had forgotten.